# app works on iphone 6plus simulator but not in iphone6 simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash

I'm developing an app that uses SQLITE and works perfectly on Iphone 6plus simulator but crash on Iphone6 simulator and also on Iphone5. I'm not sure what's the problem. Can anyone help me with that?
This is the debug error that I'm getting from Xcode

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]'

*** First throw call stack:

(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010492ae65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001043a3deb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010480e404 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 212
3   ILFCalc                             0x0000000103d85cf8 -[EditInfoViewController loadInfoToEdit] + 424
4   ILFCalc                             0x0000000103d83f76 -[EditInfoViewController viewDidLoad] + 1174
5   UIKit                               0x0000000104e6df98 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
6   UIKit                               0x0000000104e73f4f -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 120
7   UIKit                               0x0000000104ea3e44 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1203
8   UIKit                               0x0000000104eb423f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 712
9   UIKit                               0x0000000104eb53af -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
10  UIKit                               0x000000010505bff7 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
11  UIKit                               0x0000000104d8e4a3 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010874559a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108739e70 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000108739cee _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010872e475 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010875bc0a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010875c37c _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104856367 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001048562d7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010484bf2b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147
21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010484b828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000107fd2ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
23  UIKit                               0x0000000104cd7610 UIApplicationMain + 171
24  ILFCalc                             0x0000000103d898af main + 111
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010631a92d start + 1
26  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Post the code of your `loadInfoToEdit` function.  It looks like you're trying to subscript an array with `NSNotFound`

Comment: To learn how to debug a crash, please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: First you need sure that the index passing in your `objectAtIndex` is a `int` or `NSInteger`. Sometimes there ios version can ignore this or failing to correct, I have sometimes occurred.

Comment: Thank you very much the web page from raywenderlich helped me a lot to solve more than an issue... I fully appreciate your help on this!!